# how to convert express web project into window standalone application

Tags: node.js, express

is there any way to convert express web project into window standalone application. I had googled a lot and found most answer but most of them package json are like this

```
  {
  "name": "login",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "main": "index.html",
   "productName": "login",
   "engines": {
   "node": ">=4"
   },
```

but my package json something like this

```
   {
     "name": "login",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "main": "server/server.js",
     "productName": "login",
     "engines": {
      "node": ">=4"
       },
```

now my problem is that how i can convert this using nw.js can anybody suggested me solution or is there anyother way to do this note :- i don't want to write any extra code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). You will have to port it though, since there's no way to convert it 1 - 1.